# Why is there no vector component product operation?

Tags: vectors

Considering two vectors

$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbf u &= \left\langle a,b,c \right\rangle \\
\mathbf v &= \left\langle d,e,f \right\rangle
\end{align*}
$$

we have the standard vector products given by

$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbf u \cdot \mathbf v &= ad+be+cf\\
\mathbf u \times \mathbf v &= \begin{vmatrix}
\hat\imath & \hat\jmath & \hat k\\
a&b&c\\d&e&f
\end{vmatrix}.
\end{align*}
$$

However, it seems that there could also easily be defined a vector *component product*, given by

$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbf u * \mathbf v &= \left\langle ad, be, cf \right\rangle.
\end{align*}
$$

Why is this not a standard operation? Is there no use for it in mathematics?

Comment: It's conceptually meaningless, and doesn't really give any nice properties. One would expect a "product" of vectors to satisfy the property $||u||\cdot||v||=||u*v||$ (where $*$ is our supposed new vector product).

Comment: I suspect you'll find it somewhat exaggerated to say there is no such operation.  But its value depends on a particular choice of an orthonormal basis.  That is not true of the other two products you mention.

Comment: On the other hand, this is the product in the direct product of rings. That is, in the ring $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$, or $K \times K \times K$ for any field $K$.

Comment: There are component wise products. They appear in practically every numerical computing software available. In addition I would like to point out that calling these operations products is mostly a psychological terminology. All products (including products of numbers) are simply functions. Popular functions (like multiplying numbers) are so intrinsic that we view them almost as pre-functions, existing before a more general concept of function but that's what they are at the end of the day.

Comment: The operation of component-wise multiplication does not yield an integral domain.  That is, it is possible to 'multiply' two nonzero elements (e.g. $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,0)$) and obtain the zero vector.  In this respect (among others), component-wise multiplication doesn't have nice properties.

Comment: @WChargin : this is called the Hadamard product. See JohnD's answer.  People have proven tons of stuff about Hadamard products of matrices.  I don't know how often people use it for "vectors" (matrices with just one column or just one row).

Comment: @WChargin: there is an extensive literature about the Hadamard product, its properties and uses for larger matrices (with more rows and columns), so you should take blanket statements that it is useless vor vectors with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 4):

You're more than welcome to define $\text{u} * \text{v}$ as you have.  That's what makes mathematics wonderful.

The question then becomes: "How will people use it?"  You're taking the component-wise product of the elements of two vectors, and creating another vecctor out of them.  What does it do?

I can see that if you take the vectors as being the diagonal elements of two square matrices, then your product vector is the components of the trace of the matrix product.

I see that $\text{u} * \text{v} = \text{v} * \text{u}$, so it's commutative.

I see that $\text{u} * \text{1} = \text{1}$, so it behaves well with the traditional multiplicative identity element.

I see that $\text{u} * \text{0} = \text{0}$, so it doesn't create any mathematical wormholes with the zero vector.

So, yeah:  you've created $*$, and it does some things.  What else does it do?

Comment: The question at the end of your answer may have been rhetorical, but I am interested if anyone has a good answer to it.  There is an extensive literature about the Hadamard product, its properties and uses for larger matrices (with more rows and columns), so one should take blanket statements that it is useless for vectors (you made no much statement) with a grain of salt.  To your list of properties you could have added a distributive property for the Hadamard product and addition of vectors.

Comment: @StefanSmith "What else does it do?".   In game programming, we use it to apply a scale transformation that has different scaling factors along each axis (see Vector3.Scale in Unity). I realize that in linear algebra one would rather use a diagonal matrix, but it takes up unnecessary space in memory.

Answer (score 2):

More generally, the [Hadamard product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_%28matrices%29) of two $m\times n$ matrices fits your description in the sense that it is an *entrywise* product.

Thinking of $\mathbf{u}=(a,b,c)$ and $\mathbf{v}=(d,e,f)$ as $3\times 1$ matrices, their Hadamard product is the $3\times 1$ matrix $\mathbf{u}\circ\mathbf{v}=(ad,be,cf)$.

---

Keep in mind that the definitions we choose are often a function of the theorems that we can prove from those definitions.

As far as what it is good for, note the structure present: it is associative, distributive, and even commutative(!). The downside is that composition of linear maps doesn't equate to this type of matrix multiplication and this is the thrust of "usual" matrix multiplication.